# Maple code for series

Tags: matlab, maple

With thanks in advance

I have problem in writting Maple code for :
$$\sum_{\underset{\large(N+i)\ \ odd}{i=0}}^{N-1}a_{i} $$

where $N‎ \geq ‎1 $ is input.

With regards

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`sum(a[N-2i-1], i=0..floor((N-1)/2))`

Edit: and for $N+i$ even:

`sum(a[N-2i], i=0..floor(N/2))`

Comment: Thanks a lot Dear Arnaud Mortier

Comment: @Nafas You're welcome.

Comment: How is for case $(N+i) even$?

Comment: @Nafas I edited.